# How to use VSCode RemoteContainer with Minikube as Docker Daemon?

Tags: docker, visual-studio-code

I wonder if anyone has been able to use VSCode Remote Containers with Docker/Minikube setup, because I can't get it to work.

I am trying to use VSCode Remote Container Extension and I am trying to follow the quick start guide: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/containers#_quick-start-try-a-development-container

My setup is on current MacOS I have installed HyperKit, Minkube, Docker and Docker-Compose instead of Docker Desktop. See: https://medium.com/rahasak/replace-docker-desktop-with-minikube-and-hyperkit-on-macos-783ce4fb39e3

To make docker cli work on my terminal, it is important to add `eval $(minikube docker-env)` to my .zshrc file. After that I can use the docker cli just fine.

When I now try to start the devcontainer from inside VSCode, I get the error message that the docker daemon cannot be located. It seems that it uses a different bash but i am not sure which. I changed the docker command in the VSCode configuration in a way to sneak in the eval-statement from above and then it runs a little further and i can see some docker statements that show up in the console.

Eventually however, it will fail again

```
    [1303 ms] SyntaxError: Unexpected token d in JSON at position 0
 at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
 at Kp (/Users/xxx/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers-0.209.6/dist/extension/extension.js:356:1327)
 at async vo (/Users/xxx/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers-0.209.6/dist/extension/extension.js:356:751)
 at async Iu (/Users/xxx/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers-0.209.6/dist/extension/extension.js:422:1244)
 at async Sh (/Users/xxx/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers-0.209.6/dist/extension/extension.js:422:666)
 at async z5 (/Users/xxx/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers-0.209.6/dist/extension/extension.js:416:11729)
```

Maybe somebody knows which kind of shell the process is using or maybe somebody has already figured it out if it is possible to use the Minikube instead of Docker Desktop with Remote Containers.

Thanks!